# x.lastChild.nodeValue

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js">
      <script type="text/javascript">
          x=document.getElementByTagName("p");
          document.write(x.lastChild.nodeValue);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="intro">Hello World 1!</p>
      <p id="intro">Hello World 2!</p>
      <p id="intro">Hello World 3!</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the above code work. I want to show [Hello World 3!] by using the statement documetn.write(x.lastChild.nodeValue());
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

- You execute your JavaScript before the HTML has finished loading. In Consequence the `<p>` are not existent at the time you want to query them.

Simple solution would be to move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the HTML page.

- The command is `document.getElementsByTagName()` (and not `document.getElementById()` - note the added "s") and returns an array.

So here the correct syntax for you would be something like this:

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
x = x[ x.length - 1 ];
```

- Why do you want to use `document.write()`? This inserts text at the very position of the script tag.

So for debugging it would be better to use `console.log()` or `alert()`. In a productive environment, you would have a result-`<div>` for example.

So finally your code maybe could look like this in order to work:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="intro">Hello World 1!</p>
      <p id="intro">Hello World 2!</p>
      <p id="intro">Hello World 3!</p>
      <hr>
      <div id="result"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          x=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
          x = x[ x.length - 1 ];

          document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerHTML = x.nodeValue;
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```